# Problem with Cache.ItemSizeLimitExceededException Error

Tags: apex

I tried to write the session cache with a map. The map contains 17k register.

```
Cache.Session.put('keyId', map, Constant.SESSION_TIMEOUT);
```

I get this error:

> ```
> 17:58:10.645 (9646020079)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|
> [4]|this|cache.ItemSizeLimitExceededException|true|false
> ```

How can I write a bigger map into the cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I write a bigger map into the cache?

You can't. The [Platform Cache Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_platform_cache_limits.htm) entry reads:

> Maximum size of a single cached item (for put() methods)  100 KB

This means your map must be smaller than 100 KB, or 100,000 individual characters, including serialization. Basically, if `JSON.serialize(map).length() > 100000`, you won't be allowed to put the data in the cache. Consider breaking up your map into smaller fragments. You haven't said how big each entry is, but I'd guess you'd need to break them into sizes of about 1,000 keys or so, which allows 100 bytes per key-value.

Comment: the 100,000 char limit is not appropriate measurement for equating 100KB I guess. Here I am trying manually to reach that limit but still not able to. Here is my code snippet
/**
String str ;
Integer charLimit = 300000;
for(Integer i =0 ;i < charLimit ; i++){
    if(String.isBlank(str)){
        str = 'a';
    } else {
        str = str + 'a';
    }
}
Cache.OrgPartition cacheOrgPart = Cache.Org.getPartition('local.Cache');
cacheOrgPart.put('123456',str ) // this is supposed to hit the limit but it won't

Comment: @ManjunathaVP I haven't personally used cache, so I don't know what the expected behavior is. Maybe an exception, maybe truncated after the transaction completes? By the way, for testing large strings, you can just `'a'.repeat(charLimit)`. I'll look into this later and see what I come up with.

Comment: It won;t get truncated either after the transaction is completed. I have refetched the data from cache and measured the size of the data, it still remains the same. Thanks for making me notice the repeat method. I was running into CPU time out for testing large strings.